# Sql multiple file import

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert multiple csv file to `sqlserver` table. I have a procedure for doing that. It works but my all files have same column name. So instead of importing all records it just imports column name which is the first row. If I manually delete first row then it imports the other records, I have thousands of files so I cant work manually. I am posting store procedure here. Please tell me if I can change something to make this work.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_ImportMultipleFiles] @filepath varchar(500), 
    @pattern varchar(100), @TableName varchar(128)
as
set quoted_identifier off
declare @query varchar(1000)
declare @max1 int
declare @count1 int
Declare @filename varchar(100)
set @count1 =0
create table #x (name varchar(200))
set @query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+@filepath+@pattern +' /b"'
insert #x exec (@query)
delete from #x where name is NULL
select identity(int,1,1) as ID, name into #y from #x 
drop table #x
set @max1 = (select max(ID) from #y)
--print @max1
--print @count1
While @count1 <= @max1
begin
set @count1=@count1+1
set @filename = (select name from #y where [id] = @count1)
set @Query ='BULK INSERT '+ @Tablename + ' FROM '''+ @Filepath+@Filename+''' 
    WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
--print @query
exec (@query)
insert into logtable (query) select @query
end

drop table #y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the First Row option in your bulk insert statement something like...

```
BULK INSERT Table_Name 
FROM 'C:\FilePath'
WITH 
     (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' 
      ,ROWTERMINATOR   = '\n'
      ,FIRSTROW        = 2    --<-- This option here
     )
```

**Edit to your proc**

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = N'BULK INSERT '+ @Tablename + 
             N' FROM '''+ @Filepath+@Filename + 
             N'''  WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
                         ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' 
                         ,FIRSTROW = 2
                       )'
```

Comment: M.Ali thanks for reply. I tried using your code but its not working

Comment: What do you mean by its not working? do you get an error? the code didnt execute at all? if you give more information maybe we can find a solution :)

Comment: code executes perfectly but there are no records in the table. I can share result ..